# Group by a summed variable

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, distinct

```
SELECT deposit.numberSuccessfulDeposits, count(distinct userid) 
FROM deposit WHERE deposit.asOfDate between '2016-04-01 00:00:00' and '2016-04-03 23:59:59'
AND deposit.licenseeId = 1306
GROUP BY deposit.numberSuccessfulDeposits
```

Sample output

```
numberSuccessfulDeposits     count(distinct userid) 
 0   228 
 1   878 
 2   90 
 3   37 
 4   17
```

However, if Bob made 1 deposit on Monday and 3 deposits on Tuesday, then it will count towards both "1" and "3" for number of successful deposits.

```
numberSuccessfulDeposits     count(distinct userid) 
 0   ## 
 1   1 
 2   ## 
 3   1 
 4   ##
```

Ideally, it should only count towards "4"

```
numberSuccessfulDeposits     count(distinct userid) 
 0   ## 
 1   ## 
 2   ## 
 3   ## 
 4   1
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Change the grouping to user-based and sum all occurences of deposits. Then count users for each sum of those deposits:

```
SELECT
  numberSuccessfulDeposits,
  COUNT(userid) AS users_count
FROM (
  SELECT 
    sum(numberSuccessfulDeposits) AS numberSuccessfulDeposits, 
    userid
  FROM deposit
  WHERE asOfDate between '2016-04-01 00:00:00' and '2016-04-03 23:59:59'
    AND licenseeId = 1306
  GROUP BY userid
  ) t
GROUP BY numberSuccessfulDeposits
```

*Edit*: Grouping deposints into 0, 1, 2, 3+ category would look like that:

```
SELECT
  numberSuccessfulDeposits,
  COUNT(userid) AS user_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE WHEN numberSuccessfulDeposits >= 3 THEN '3+' ELSE numberSuccessfulDeposits::TEXT END AS numberSuccessfulDeposits,
    userid
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      sum(numberSuccessfulDeposits) AS numberSuccessfulDeposits, 
      userid
    FROM deposit
    WHERE asOfDate between '2016-04-01 00:00:00' and '2016-04-03 23:59:59'
      AND licenseeId = 1306
    GROUP BY userid
    ) t
  ) f
GROUP BY numberSuccessfulDeposits
```

Comment: I don't think `DISTINCT` can be used with `SUM`, only with `COUNT`. And even if it can, it's not right. If Bob makes 1 deposit on Monday and 1 on Wednesday, this will just count them as 1 deposit, not 2.

Comment: Yes, it can be used with `SUM`. Why not? For the latter part - I forgot about the data column, so you're right, I've removed it, thanks.

Comment: I thought it was a special feature of `COUNT`, but I just checked the manual and you're right -- it also works with `AVG`, `MAX`, `MIN`, etc. I'm not sure *why* you'd ever want to sum/average only distinct values, and for `MAX` and `MIN` I don't see how it could make a difference.

Comment: I also see no reason to use it for both `MAX` and `MIN`. I see a use for `AVG` when you only want to account the value into average once to perform an average across distinct set (denormalised data, or sth like that) and for `SUM` it could be: _let's see on the receipt how much money was spent when each product was only counted once_, but this involves `CASE` statement.

Comment: But that would be wrong. What if two different products have the same price? `SUM(DISTINCT price)` just compares the prices, not the products. It seems like something that was put in for generality, but probably has no real use.

Comment: You're right, I didn't stop to think on the example. This would only work for single column queries without `CASE`. :-) May still find some odd use, but I probably have never used it in production.

Comment: Ok. Both Kamil G. and Barmar's suggestions worked. Now, how do i group everything above 3 deposits into a 3+ category ?

Comment: Edited my answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the per-user sum in a subquery, then the per-total count in the main query.

```
SELECT totalDeposits, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT userid, SUM(numberOfSuccessfulDeposits) AS totalDeposits
      FROM deposit 
      WHERE deposit.asOfDate between '2016-04-01 00:00:00' and '2016-04-03 23:59:59'
      AND deposit.licenseeId = 1306
      GROUP BY userid) AS subquery
GROUP BY totalDeposits
```

Comment: Ok. Both Kamil G. and Barmar's suggestions worked. Now, how do i group everything above 3 deposits into a 3+ category ?